# how to create custom functions in class range

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a custom function i.e. 
myrange.ckeck_if_included(row,col,numrow,numcol) 
that returns a boolean that says me if the range given in input is included into myrange. Is it possible to create this function in class range? And how to refer my function to myrange?
Thanks
franko

Comment: I do not exactly understand what you want to do, but I think it is possible, though in a slightly different way. Take a look at the [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries) and let us know if this helps you.

Comment: I mean that I only am able to create functions like function ckeck_if_included(row1,col1,numrow1,numcol1,row2,col2,numrow2,numcol2) that I assume is placed in no class, but I'd like to create a fuction I can apply to a range.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a proxy object to do this. Here's a general proxy-making utility:

```
function proxy(obj) {
  var x = {};
  Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { x[k] =
      function() { return obj[k].apply(obj, [].slice.call(arguments, 0)); }})
  return x;
}
```

In your case you could then do

```
r=proxy(SpreadsheetApp.openById("...").getSheetByName("Sheet1").getActiveRange());
r.myFunction=function () { ... }
```

And more generally you can even replace top-level objects with proxies:

```
GmailApp = proxy(GmailApp);
GmailApp.myFunction = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to extend an Object/Class of the Google-Services? This does not work, you get an exception "Object does not allow properties to be added or changed" if you try like this:

```
r=SpreadsheetApp.openById("...").getSheetByName("Sheet1").getActiveRange();
r.myFunction=function () { ... }
```