# Where do I find the Paragraph.prototype or how else can I extend it?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I wanted to extend the [`Paragraph`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#) (type? class? object?) and add some repeating functions to it like:

```
Paragraph.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    return this.getText().trim().length === 0;
};
```

> ReferenceError: "Paragraph" is not defined. (line 23, file "Code")

or

```
DocumentApp.Paragraph.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    return this.getText().trim().length === 0;
};
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property "prototype" from undefined. (line 23, file "Code")

but none of these work. I put this code in a `Code.gs` file and tried to use it but the compiler says there is no such thing.

What is this thing actually and how can I add something to it?

Comment: Related: [how to create custom functions in class range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14424148/1595451)

Comment: Related: [Are javascript objects “open” like Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17330228/1595451)

Comment: I don't understand why someone would upvote a question that appears to have been covered previously (several times, by all appearances)..

Comment: @Tedinoz Mhmm why not? Not everyone is a Javascript expert and can come up with the proper wording to find the other questions. I didn't know it's a general problem with Google scripts. Sometimes it's just easier to ask and risk a duplicate than search for a couple of days with the wrong terms.

Comment: Your reputation and time on StackOverflow is well beyond mine, but I decline to defer to you on this. Even you should know that your response is not an attitude that is encouraged. You would be aware of [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) _and why it is necessary_. If experienced "old hands" aren't going to respect the 'rules', then we shouldn't be surprised by any decline in the quality of questions.

Comment: @Tedinoz I'm not sure I can follow you. What attitude do you mean exactly and what rules? I also don't understand what your link has to do with my question. I also would like to remind you that comments are not the right place for such discussion but I can gladly talk about it with you in chat.